# Read an uint32 as a float without overflow?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm working on a program that does that kind of things : it takes an array of float values, and encodes the values three by three in a base64 string. When the whole array is encoded, if there are some values left (number < 3), it encodes them and adds the necessary `'='` (for more informations, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)).

Anyway, here is not the problem. My problem is that, at the very beginning of this base64 string, I need to indicate the number of floats following, but as an uint32. However, I'm forced to use my function using floats... So I have to use a hack, and initialize a pointer to an uint32, but read it as a float.

Here is how I do it:

```
uint32_t *ivalue = (uint32_t *)malloc(sizeof (uint32_t));
float *fvalue = (float *)ivalue;
// (...) some code
*ivalue = 2 * sizeof (float); // The value I want, 2 * 4 in this case (on my computer)
tempoCoor.push_back(*fvalue);
```

`tempoCoor` is a std::vector I fill, and when the size is 3, I encode its content and empty it.

However, there is a problem with my *hackish* method... When I compute values smaller than 256 (I think this is this value), everything is fine, but not when my values are greater or equal than 256. Why is that ? How could I fix it ?

If I was not clear in any way, please ask me more details. I can explain more if needed.

Comment: That code is highly unsafe and risky, not to mention, why are you using `malloc` in C++? (and C-style casts on top of that).

Comment: @UnholySheep : Could you suggest anything to help me ?

Comment: Unnecessary allocation and invalid conversion through pointer aside, I fail to see why you need type punning anyway.

Comment: Also what exactly does happen? You state it is not working fine, but that does not tell us what is going on

Comment: @UnholySheep I stated that it worked, but only for values < 256. I don't understand why, that's why I asked here.

Comment: Yes but what happens for values >=256? If you don't give us that information, we have a hard time helping you. Also as zch stated, you don't need the allocation and that conversion is just wrong (and possibly what is causing you problems)

Comment: Well, for exemple, let's say I push the integer 16 in my vector and interpret it as a float in my function. I'll get some base64 string. If I decode it, I'll have binary (32 * 3 bits to be exact) which will go like this : first 32 bits have value 16 if interpreted as 32 bits Integer, and the next two 32 bits chunks will have their good values, if interpreted as floats. I know it's super dumb, but that's the norm of the software I'm forced to use. I have to type them as 32bit integers. And this bores me, because my function is made for floats. Hence, the hack.

Comment: @UnholySheep : Oh yeah sorry. For values >= 256 it's just nonsense, like 10e-46 values. I don't know where these values come from

Comment: I think your design is flawed. Encoding function shouldn't expect `float` and reject `int`. It should work with any byte sequence, you can use for example `std::vector<uint8_t>` or pointer and length. Use `memcpy` to copy bytes.

Comment: Rather than using pointers you should use the values themselves, also use C++ style casting (`static_cast`) as this will even tell you if what you are trying to do makes sense at all. You are simply trying to "reinterpret" a pointer to `uint32` which has a different layout in memory. Once the values become too big your float reads some bits as part of the exponent, which give you "wrong" results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here some explanations on what is wrong with that code:
1. Why are you using `malloc` in C++? It is a bad habit and only in some few special cases appropriate. Use `new` instead! (Also don't cast `malloc` [in C] or at least use C++ casts)
2. Why are you even allocating memory on the heap? it seems completely unnecessary in this case.
3. Don't use C-Style casts in C++ code - C++ casts (`static_cast`, etc.) are safer and contain some error checking.

So here is how this code might look like.

```
uint32_t ivalue = 2 * sizeof(float); //simply assigning the value  
// ... some Code
tempoCoor.push_back(static_cast<float>(ivalue)); //using proper C++ cast to convert
```

As you were using memory on the heap and accessing it directly, by reinterpreting a pointer (which would be equivalent to `reinterpret_cast`) you are using the data which was written there as if it was a float, which it obviously wasn't. Once your values got big enough some of the bits were interpreted as being part of the exponent and you received wrong values.

Comment: Well, that's working perfectly. I'm not really used to C++ so thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Uh. Well, actually it doesn't work at all. Check out these two screenshots : [1](http://i.imgur.com/CzGlMz2.png) and [2](http://i.imgur.com/UP19rh2.png). The first one is the one I generated using your code. The decoded base64 has the correct value (24 in this case) if decoded as a float32. This is not correct. The second image is the correct case (file generated by the software). As you can see, the value here is good if decoded as a signed (maybe unsigned) integer. It worked with my dirty method... Why doesn't it work with yours ?

Comment: Considering that your "hack" did not give correct results for >=256 I wouldn't say it worked :P However this seems unrelated to what code I wrote, but rather how your code handles the values it is given (which does not appear in your original question) [Also my code is meant as a guideline, given what information you have provided me with]. As I do not know how the rest of your code handles these conversions, I will not be able to give you an answer to that

Comment: Yeah, my bad, it didn't work really well but at least when it worked it worked the way I wanted! :P
Yeah you're right, maybe I should just change my function. I'm gonna give it a try. Thanks anyway!